# How to go from an Activity to PreferenceFragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am having trouble navigating from my main page which is an `Activity` to the account settings page which uses `PreferenceFragment`.

I'm trying to achieve this via the navigation drawer, when the item is clicked, the settings page should be displayed. All my other pages are a `Fragment` except the account settings page and all work properly (except for the settings page). I thought `PreferenceFragment` extends from `Fragment` so surely it should work?

**MainPage.java**

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (position == 0) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(1))
                .commit();

    } else if (position == 1) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, Search.newInstance(2))
                .commit();

    }

    else if (position == 2) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, Favourites.newInstance(3))
                .commit();
    }

    else if (position == 3) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, History.newInstance(4))
                .commit();

    }

    else if (position == 4) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, AccountSettings.newInstance(5))
                .commit();

    }

}
```

**AccountSettings.java**

```
public class AccountSettings extends PreferenceFragment {

    Activity mActivity;

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public static AccountSettings newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        AccountSettings fragment = new AccountSettings();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    //inflating layout
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        restoreActionBar();

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mActivity = activity;

    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle("Account Settings");
    }

    public AccountSettings() {

    }
}
```

It would give me the following error on **MainPage.java**:

```
'replace(int, android.support.v4.app.Fragment)' in 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction' cannot be applied to '(int, com.example.laptop.whatsfordinner.AccountSettings)'
```

I've tried changing it to a `Fragment` and it works, but I want to use `PreferenceFragment`, so how can I get it to work?

Surely I'm just missing something really obvious?

Comment: One option would be to use [PreferenceFragmentCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat.html), which was created for this exact situation.  See here for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487206/inner-preferencescreen-not-opens-with-preferencefragmentcompat

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  `getFragmentManager` for PreferenceFragment. Because they don't extend the support v4 version of Fragment class.