# Add PrefererenceScreen to PreferenceScreen from code

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, preferences, preferencescreen

I have a PreferenceFragmentCompat that I populate with a call to:

```
setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings, rootKey);
```

After this I have a screen with editable text and checkboxes and what not. Is it possible to add a inner PreferenceScreen after this? I have tried using addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.additional_settings) and constructing a new PreferenceScreen in code, but I always end up with a error stating that the newly added preference element is not a PreferenceScreen. I am able to add EditTextPreferences and such, but PreferenceScreen is giving me trouble.

I am using appcompat.

Comment: Why you want to do that ? you can always display a dialog box.

Comment: I have a layout design that I am implementing. Though a dialog box could achieve the same thing, I am hoping I could match the layout design.

Comment: Implement custom prefscreen is a last option .

Comment: My PreferenceScreen already uses a custom layout file and has custom DialogPreferences, so what do you mean with a custom preferencescreen? My Fragment extends a PreferenceFragmentCompat, but I am unable to add a inner PreferenceScreen to it in code, but through XML it works.

Comment: I think you should read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487206/inner-preferencescreen-not-opens-with-preferencefragmentcompat

Comment: I have read that before. That is regarding the issue that the PreferenceScreens fo not open. I have a PreferenceScreen containing PreferenceScreens that open, but I have defined them in the XML. If I try to create them in code, I get an error saying they are not instances of PreferenceScreen.